# Long delay on omniauth callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, thin

OmniAuth (Facebook and LinkedIn) was working for me for months.

Without any code change, I started seeing a very long delay on the callback from Facebook/LinkedIn.

It now takes about 40 seconds from:

```
Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback?state=e600c4acbb0e10f40....
```

to:

```
Processing by AuthenticationsController#create as HTML....
```

I saw [an issue](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/31) on that, but no resolution worked for me.

Anyone seen that? How can I solve this/figure out what's going on?

**--EDIT 1--**

I ran the flow with curl and found that calls to Facebook take a very long time:

```
time curl --data "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=[MY CLINET ID]&client_secret=[MY CLIENT SECRET]&redirect_uri=[MY REDIRECT URI]&code=[THE CODE I GOT]" https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
>> access_token=AAAA....ZDZD&expires=5183693
real 0m20.459s
user 0m0.004s
sys 0m0.008s

time curl -H "Authorization: Bearer AAAA....ZDZD" https://graph.facebook.com/me
>> {....}
real 0m20.706s
user 0m0.012s
sys 0m0.008s
```

**--EDIT 2--**

It seems that every call with curl takes 20 seconds more than it should. I tried with Google:

```
time curl http://www.google.com
>> <HTML>....</HTML>

real    0m20.253s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.004s
```

but when I try with IP:

```
time curl http://173.194.44.17
>> <HTML>....</HTML>

real    0m0.647s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.000s
```

I found a hint in some website that it may have to do with slow DNS resolution. The browser on the same machine seems to work fine.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce the delay using wget or curl? (Using the same environment as your app)

Comment: I wasn't able to do it with curl because it's difficult to make the same call with curl -- I have to run through the entire OAuth handshake in order to get to this final call.

Comment: OK. @TheIrishGuy, I managed to run the entire flow with curl. It seems that every call to Facebook from the backend takes about 20 seconds. See my edit for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. This was a local issue, related to slow DNS resolving in Ubuntu 12.04, which is a known issue. What solved it for me was configuring my system to work with google DNS instead of automatic configuration.